# How to get the little indicator triangle to custom action in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

How to get the little gray triangle (indicating a spinner/submenus usually) to a custom action in the ActionBar? I manage to add submenus to my action, but don't see a way to add the small triangle in the lower right corner.
(Same when using android.widget.ShareActionProvider)

How I want it (sample from API Demos):

[image]

I am able to edit submenus, but not getting the small gray triangle to the lower right of my action icon:

[image]

My code for the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_new_form"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_form"
          android:title="@string/menu_new_form"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_size"
                  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_by_size"
                  android:title="Form 1"
                  android:onClick="onSort" />
            <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_alpha"
                  android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_sort_alphabetically"
                  android:title="Form 2"
                  android:onClick="onSort" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked in the sources of Android, and here's how Google implement it:

[image]

(it's ic_menu_share_holo_light.png)

So if Google draws this little triangle directly in the icon image, I suppose it's the best practice currently.

Answer (score 0):

That gray triangle in the first picture is available when you set a button to start activity by using `Intent.createChooser(intent, "heading")`.

However, in your technique, you are providing a menu option which contains sub-menus. To make it simple, you may simply create an icon which has a grey triangle at bottom.

example to share a message by asking user to pick option:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, note.getHead());
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is a demo message");

context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share message"));
```

Comment: Do you mean I could achieve it by creating my own intent-filter and use that custom intent then for my chooser? Creating an icon with the grey triangle is what I want to avoid, it's too much 'manual' work, doesn't sound right. I do get such triangle on the left-hand side in my ActionBar when choosing "ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST"; but on the right side for my custom action, I can't get it. I will try the custom intent+chooser. Referring to your first sentence: where to set the button, in onCreateActionView and return it? Thanks.

Comment: Another reason I don't want to manually draw the triangle in code is that the appearance might change over time with new Android versions / themes, eventually.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to get the triangle with the Intent.createChooser. When I set it in the button.setOnClickListener in onCreateActionView it won't show - obviously, because I doubt that the ActionBar will 'parse the code logic' in advance to figure out what intent the action might actually call at a later point and based on that, show (if it's a chooser) or not show a triangle. Can you clarify? Thanks!